# Open array of class element

Tags: delphi

I have a class that inside defines another class as array like this:

```
class1 = class
private
    fTag : string
    .
    .
published
    property Tag : read fTag write fTag;
end;

arrayOfClass1 = array of class1;

class2 =class
private
    FTvalue1 : string;
    FTaggedValues: arrayOfClass1;
    procedure SetTaggedValues (.....);
        do something;

published
    property value1 : read FTvalue1 write FTValue1;
    property  TaggedValues : arrayOfClass1 Index read FTaggedValues write SetTaggedValues;

end;
```

My problem is that I can't find a way to add an element to property TaggedValues.
So I am here to ask which is the proper way to initialize, redim and create element?

---

Thanks for reply mr. Guillot

Probably I omitted too much info about my problem so I'll try to explain myself  a little better.

The class involved are coming from a WSDL and they inherit each from other in this way:

```
StdOrderDto2 = class(TRemotable)
PrtOrderDto2 = class(StdOrderDto2)
PrtOrderColorDecksDto2 = class(PrtOrderDto2)
```

this is the snipped code of interested class:

```
  StdOrderDto2 = class(TRemotable)
  private
    .
    .
    FTaggedValues: ArrayOfStdTagValueDto;
    procedure SetTaggedValues(Index: Integer; const AArrayOfStdTagValueDto: ArrayOfStdTagValueDto);
    .
    . 
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    .
    property TaggedValues:        ArrayOfStdTagValueDto  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL) read FTaggedValues write SetTaggedValues stored TaggedValues_Specified;
    .
  end;
```

where:

```
  ArrayOfStdTagValueDto = array of StdTagValueDto2;
```

and:

```
  StdTagValueDto2 = class(TRemotable)
  private
  .
  .
  (simple datatype are involved)    
  published
  .
  (etc)
  .
  end;
```

So my first question:
Can I use this class (PrtOrderColorDecksDto2) for make a call to server also if the class in not a direct descendant of a TRemotable class?
I guess yes because the ancestor (StdOrderDto2) is a TRemotable... But I am not sure about this..

Second question:
For "populate" TaggedValues I use this snippet:

```
var temp : PrtOrderColorDecksDto2;
.
.
.
begin
    temp := PrtOrderColorDecksDto2.create;
        temp.someproperty1 := 5;
        temp.someproperty2 := 'Five';
        ....etc.....
    setlength(temp.TaggedValues, 3);  --->>> I got in compiler error "[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(38): E2197 Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter"
        temp.TaggedValues[0] := StdTagValueDto2.create;

        temp.TaggedValues[0].someproperty1 := 5;
    ...etc etc....

end;
```

So my question is: Why do I get an E2197 compiler error?
And once someone can explain me what I made wrong, can provide me a way to solve this?

Comment: Use e.g. an indexed property (in a right way, not like in such incompilable code presented here) and before you store the value check if you're in bounds of that array. If not, resize it. Or make a method for adding elements.

Comment: Save yourself the hassle and use [TList<T>](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList) instead - if possible.

Comment: Any comment???????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ViRuSTriNiTy said, a TList< Class1 >  instead of an Array will manage them for you.

But if you still prefer to use an array, just add a AddTag method in Class2 to add a new TagValue, and a Destroy method to free all its tags when freeing your object. No initialization is needed.

```
class2 = class
private
  ...
  FTaggedValues = array of class1;
published
  ..
  procedure AddTagValue(TagValue: class1);
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

implementation

procedure class2.AddTagValue(TagValue: class1);
begin
  SetLength(FTaggedValues, Length(FTaggedValues) + 1);
  FTaggedValues[Length(FTaggedValues) - 1] := TagValue;
end;

destructor class2.Destroy;
var TagValue: class1;
begin
  for TagValue in FTaggedValues do TagValue.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, finally I write the (missing) method to add the array element.